Waveshare SIM7600E-H 4G HAT support on OpenWrt
I would like to use Waveshare SIM7600E-H 4G HAT on OpenWrt (ideally) or at least on Raspbian. I would ideally like understand what is needed to be done from the command line (better than use luci or any other gui configuration).
Following I found from various sources for OpenWrt, Raspbian Raspbian - NDIS dial-up and self-starting, Raspbian - RNDIS Dial-Up

boot/config.txt should have at least enable_uart=1. Anything else? Raspbian instructions mention also dtoverlay=disable-bt.

Linux kernel must support option module, via CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_OPTION=m kernel config option (or =y builtin module). I'm not sure if this is enabled for OpenWrt, it should be for Raspbian kernel.

Minimal kernel version. I suppose that kernel 5.15 which is in OpenWrt 23.05 should be new enough, the module is very old and SIM7600 support was added in kernel 4.20 (MBIM support) and in 5.2 (RNDIS mode).

Support for Raspberry Pi not (yet) mainlined kernel code. I see /boot/config.txt mentioned in OpenWrt Raspberry Pi wiki, which should mean that hopefully anything which kernel needs for Raspberry Pi and it's not in the mainline kernel is patched in OpenWrt kernel.
https://openwrt.org/toh/start claims that OpenWrt 23.05.5 supports all RPI versions, just the newest Raspberry Pi 5 needs snapshot (the future version).

user space configuration - module should be visible


lsusb |grep -i Qualcomm
ls -la /dev/ttyUSB[0-4]

If not, it's needed to manually load module and even configure the mode
modprobe option
echo "1e0e 9011" > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/generic/new_id
# or
echo "1e0e 9011" > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id

In archive https://files.waveshare.com/upload/2/29/SIM7600X-4G-HAT-Demo.7z (referenced in Raspbian) is file  SIM7600X-4G-HAT-Demo/Raspberry/c/sim7600_4G_hat_init which sets some GPIO values:
echo "4" > /sys/class/gpio/export
sleep 0.1
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/direction
echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value
echo "6" > /sys/class/gpio/export
sleep 0.1
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio6/direction
echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio6/value

I suppose this example is not needed for actual Waveshare use.

libqmi is of course supported for both distros,  OpenWrt 23.05 has 1.32.4 (quite new version).

